# while using an action, how to reduce image size to fit inside a shape

Tags: actionscript

While writing an action, I want to open an image from my computer, copy, close image and paste it into my current project. Now I want that image to be resized to fit into a frame that is on on one of my layers

So it has to automated and done as part of the action, and not done by pressing Free Transform and dragging the handles myself.

Comment: as3 or as2?....

Answer (score 0):

```
imgWidth.width = shape.width;
imgHeight.height = shape.height;
```